# Largest possible volume of a rectangular prism constructed from a plane without a lid

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to construct a fish tank, and in order to save money I want to only have to use one single sheet of acrylic perspex. The sheet is sized 2440mmx1200mmx20mm. As such, what is the largest volume rectangular prism I can construct from this sheet, with the following conditions:

1. Each surface must be whole, i.e, I cannot stitch together multiple cuts of the plane to make up one of the surface of the tank.
2. I don't mind having off cuts (excess, unused acrylic).
3. I don't need to use acrylic for a lid of the tank, so the acrylic can be used on the other edges.
   Thank you.

Comment: I suspect you are asking a real question, not a made up math problem. I'm pretty sure the optimal solution is to cut some waste squares from the four corners and then imagine folding the edge pieces up. If that's the case then finding the optimal size of the squares is a simple calculus problem. Someone might answer for you here. Without calculus you can figure it out numerically with a little experimentation. (If this is an actual math problem you've been assigned then you must [edit] the question to show your work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the full sheet, cut a base of 1200 mm x 640 mm. The remainder of the sheet should be cut into three equal parts of 1200 mm x 600 mm. Two of these will be the front and back of the aquarium. Cut the third part in half to create two pieces of 600 mm x 600 mm for the left and right sides of the aquarium. The interior dimensions of the assembled aquarium will be 116 cm x 60 cm x 60 cm, with a total volume of 417.6 liters.

[image]